# Building a PC - PSU information

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, cryptomining

We already bought this parts for our first mining rig, but have no idea which PSU is able to take care of this hardware:
1-ASRock H110 Pro BTC+ 13GPU Mining Motherboard CryptoCurrency
2-Intel Core i3-7100 7th Gen Core Desktop Processor 3M Cache,3.90 GHz
3-Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB DDR4 DRAM 3000MHz C15 Memory Kit for DDR4 Systems
4-Samsung 850 PRO - 256GB - 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD
5-SAPPHIRE Pulse Radeon RX 580 8G GDDR5 Dual HDMI/DVI-D/Dual DPGraphCard Black

The idea is to add more graphic cards in near future.
For the power consumption, Is it better a bigger PSU? or two smaller? taking in consideration the system running more efficiently.
Any additional information is more than welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Mining on GPUs doesn't look like a good idea anymore though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you populate all 7 x1 slots each one has a max of 225w according to the website I found.  That is 1575w just for the graphics cards.

You will need at least 2, possible 3, PSU to power this rig depending on if each GPU maxes out.  1000w and above start getting into the crazy expensive price range.  Probably better with 3 PSU at 600w or 700w(to be safe).

In addition, you will need a dedicated outlet preferably 20 amp.  Technically the 15A outlet has 1800w, but due to power supply inefficiencies it may exceed that number.  So either a 20A circuit or 2 15 amp circuits otherwise you will trip the circuit breaker.   You can not just change breakers, 20A need 12 gauge wire, not just 14 like 15 amps.